# How many cores can I use when using **make -j**?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using MacBook with M1 chip (10 CPU cores with 8 P cores and 2 E cores, 24 GPU cores) and want to compile some program, I wonder how I can know the number of cores I can use to compile?
Simply, what should x be in **make -jx**?

Comment: x should be about twice the number of cores. But it can be any number. I'd try 16. Or no number at all and let'r rip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter:

`` $ make -j `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` ``

so the answer is :
`` x = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` ``

where the backstick characters means a command substitution, ie the result of the command inside the backsticks.

Comment: Thank you, and if I got output of **sysctl -n hw.ncpu** is 10, and I typed **make -j11**, what will happen? It will use 10 cores or 1 core?

Comment: `-j` specify the number of jobs make will do in parallel ; it is usual to set this number according to the num of your available cpu threads (ie num of core*num of cpu/core), but you can set more if you like or just leave `-j` alone. I'm not sure it will make any difference. Remember that one job could require another sub-make job (or another task), which in turn could require more threads and so on. I never use more than `max cpu minus one` myself, in order to keep control on my system when I compile/make very big apps (eg Firefox). The gmake man page worth a read.